# Is there any way to optimize the code for faster work?

Tags: python, tkinter, optimization

I finished writing the translator program using Python and Tkinter. I used automatic translation, without a button, and because of this, the application slows down a lot. Is there any way to optimize or speed up the translation process?
If you have any advice, I'll be glad to listen, but I'm new to Python.
[And I'm also interested in the question, is it possible to change the text inside the combobox?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgVc1.png)

/main

```
from languages import lang, lang_to_translate
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from googletrans import Translator

def defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()

def get_choice1(event):
    global choice_language1
    choice_language1 = language_selection1.get()

def get_choice2(event):
    global choice_language2
    choice_language2 = language_selection2.get()
    dest = lang.index(choice_language2)
    global language_abbreviation
    language_abbreviation = lang_to_translate[dest]
    print(language_abbreviation)

def ex_button():
    c1 = language_selection1.get()
    c2 = language_selection2.get()
    label1.configure(text=c1)
    label2.configure(text=c2)
    language_selection1.set(c2)
    language_selection2.set(c1)
    get_choice1('event')

def do_translation(event):
    choice_language1 = language_selection1.get()
    choice_language2 = language_selection2.get()
    text = text1.get("1.0", END).strip()

    translator = Translator()
    translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest=f'{language_abbreviation}')

    text2.delete("1.0", END)
    text2.insert(END, translated_text.text)

root = Tk()

app_width = 800
app_height = 500
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

root.title('Переводчик')
root['bg'] = '#1D1B26'
root.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

language_selection1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values = lang, font='Comfortaa 10', )
language_selection1.current(1)
language_selection1.place(relx=0.16,y=50)
language_selection1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', get_choice1)
language_selection1.bind('<FocusIn>', defocus)

label1 = Label(root)

exchange_button = PhotoImage(file='transfer.png')
img_label = Label(image=exchange_button)
exchange_button = exchange_button.subsample(18,18)
exchange_button1 = Button(root, image=exchange_button,background='#2ee59d',borderwidth=0, command=ex_button)
exchange_button1.place(relx=0.49,y=50)

language_selection2 = ttk.Combobox(root, values = lang, font='Comfortaa 10', )
language_selection2.set('Выберите язык')
language_selection2.place(relx=0.66,y=50)
language_selection2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', get_choice2)
language_selection2.bind('<FocusIn>', defocus)

first_frame = Frame(root, bg='Black')
first_frame.place(x=41, y=100,width= 250, height=200) #127

text1 = Text(first_frame, bg = 'White')
text1.bind('<Any-KeyRelease>', do_translation)
text1.place(x=0,y=0,width= 250, height=200)

label2 = Label(root)

second_frame = Frame(root, bg='Black')
second_frame.place(x=528, y=100,width= 250, height=200) #441

text2 = Text(second_frame, bg = 'White')
text2.place(x=0,y=0,width= 250, height=200)

root.mainloop()
```

/languages

```
    lang = ['Belarusian',
        'English',
        'German',
        'Italian',
        'Japanese',
        'Kazakh',
        'Kyrgyz',
        'Norwegian',
        'Polish',
        'Russian',
        'Spanish',
        'Swedish',
        'Turkish',
        'Ukrainian', ]

lang_to_translate =['be',
                    'en',
                    'de',
                    'it',
                    'ja',
                    'kk',
                    'ky',
                    'no',
                    'pl',
                    'ru',
                    'es',
                    'sv',
                    'tr',
                    'uk', ]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you timed operations to discover where the slowness is?

Comment: HI.No, I'm a newbie. I had an idea and with the help of different sites and YouTube, I looked at how to use the functions and methods I needed.

Comment: This code won't run. Please remove the use of an external image. Also, the code seems to rely on a variable named `language_abbreviation`, but it isn't defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to optimize or speed up the translation process?

You shouldn't be attempting to do the translation every time the user presses a key. Since the translation takes more than a couple hundred milliseconds, you should wait until the user has stopped typing so that you're not forcing a pause between every character.

You can use tkinter's `after` method to schedule the translation to happen in the future. With each key release you can cancel and reschedule the translation. If the user stops typing for a second or two, the translation will happen.

I can't run your code, but here's a brief illustration of the technique:

```
import tkinter as tk
import googletrans


after_id = None
translator = googletrans.Translator()

def do_translation():
    source = input_text.get("1.0", "end").strip()
    translated = translator.translate(source, dest="it")
    output_text.delete("1.0", "end")
    output_text.insert("end", translated.text)

def schedule_translation(event):
    global after_id
    if after_id is not None:
        event.widget.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = event.widget.after(1000, do_translation)

root = tk.Tk()
input_text = tk.Text(root)
output_text = tk.Text(root)
input_text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
output_text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

input_text.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", schedule_translation)

root.mainloop()
```

For a more robust solution you can do the translation in a separate thread or process, but multithreading and multiprocessing adds a lot of complexity.

Comment: Thank you very much, and what about combobox can I change the text of the list?

Comment: @KirillTikhov: Yes, you can change the text in the combobox.

Comment: How? can you tell me, I was looking for an answer, but I didn't find anything